# Makefile only works on terminal, fails when using Emacs

Tags: c, linux, makefile, emacs, linux-device-driver

I am currently trying to write basic kernel module on linux. I can compile the source code on terminal without any error

```shell
~/Desktop/kernelDriver$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-7642-generic/build M=/home/cryonayes/Desktop/kernelDriver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-7642-generic'
CC [M]  /home/cryonayes/Desktop/kernelDriver/basicModule.o
MODPOST /home/cryonayes/Desktop/kernelDriver/Module.symvers
CC [M]  /home/cryonayes/Desktop/kernelDriver/basicModule.mod.o
LD [M]  /home/cryonayes/Desktop/kernelDriver/basicModule.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-7642-generic'
```

But when I try to compile with same files on Emacs I get this error

```shell
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/Desktop/kernelDriver/" -*-
Compilation started at Wed Mar  3 20:42:07
   
make
make -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-7642-generic/build M=/home/cryonayes/Desktop/kernelDriver modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.8.0-7642-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2    
Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Wed Mar  3 20:42:07
```

It says **No such file or directory.** but it actually exists.

Here is the content of my Makefile

```makefile
obj-m += basicModule.o
    
KERNEL_DIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
    
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

What causes this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the `/lib/modules/5.8.0-7642-generic/build` is a symlink to `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-7642-generic`.

1. You can use `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)` instead and try again.
2. Add a `test` rule to show information about `-C`'s state as follows;

```
test:
    stat $(KERNEL_DIR)
```

This should show what and where it's pointing to.

If you're in GUI session, something might have sandboxed your emacs while terminal is running without it. You may have some kind of "fake-root" to isolate it from vulnerabilities.